# Importing a Scala project from github into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, github, egit

I've installed EGit plugin in my Eclipse Helios with latest Scala IDE plugin beta. I've imported it as a "general project" using clone and I can't find any Configure -> Add Scala nature option ... what am I doing wrong? (can't compile/run/add libraries etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the EGit Plug-in, but do you also have the option to import it as a Java project? The "Add Scala Nature" option is only available for Java projects.

If you can't create it as a Java project, you can also just modify the generated .project file and add the Java nature to it manually:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
```

(taken from http://enarion.net/programming/eclipse-change-general-to-java-project/)

Answer (score 0):

One recommended approach would be first to make your GitHub project compiled/run with **[sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/)** (which ensures both IDE-independence and third-party library dependency management).

The [sbt-eclifsify](https://github.com/musk/SbtEclipsify) can easily generates `.classpath` and `.project` files for the Eclipse IDE from the sbt project.
The class [`ProjectFile.scala`](https://github.com/musk/SbtEclipsify/blob/master/src/main/scala/de/element34/sbteclipsify/ProjectFile.scala) details how the `.project` file is build.